# Convert base 10 to base 2 in SQL Server for very large numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, binary, decimal

On SQL Server 2017 I have a base 10 number of type `DECIMAL(38,0)` which I need to convert to its base 2 representation.

This works fine for smaller numbers, but fails with the target order of magnitude:

```
DECLARE @var1 DECIMAL(38, 0) = 2679226456636072036565806253187530752;
WITH A
     AS (SELECT @var1 AS NUMBER, 
                CAST('' AS VARCHAR(125)) AS BITS
         UNION ALL
         SELECT CAST(ROUND(NUMBER / 2, 0, 1) AS DECIMAL(38, 0)),
                CAST(BITS + CAST(NUMBER % 2 AS VARCHAR(125)) AS VARCHAR(125))
         FROM A
         WHERE NUMBER > 0)
     SELECT NUMBER, 
            RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 125) + CASE
                                            WHEN BITS = ''
                                            THEN '0'
                                            ELSE REVERSE(BITS)
                                        END, 125) AS BIN_VALUE
     FROM A
     WHERE NUMBER = 0;
```

The error message reads `Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type numeric.`

I have also tried other approaches, but each has failed due to the magnitude of the original value. Any help with performing this conversion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since I still encounter the overflow error with larger numbers I have posted a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505606/sql-server-retain-decimal-scale-and-precision-for-operations-on-very-lage-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--DECLARE @var1 DECIMAL(38, 0) = 2679226456636072036565806253187530752;
DECLARE @var1 DECIMAL(38, 0) = 99999567999999999999999999999999999999;
WITH A
AS 
(
    SELECT @var1 AS NUMBER, 
        CAST('' AS VARCHAR(130)) AS BITS
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(
         cast(round(NUMBER*0.1, 0, 1) as decimal(38,0))*5 --high part
            + 
            round(cast('0.'+right(NUMBER, 1) as decimal(10,2))* 5, 0, 1) --low part
         --ROUND(NUMBER * 0.5, 0, 1)
         AS DECIMAL(38, 0)),
         CAST(BITS + CAST(NUMBER % 2 AS VARCHAR(125)) AS VARCHAR(130))
     FROM A
     WHERE NUMBER > 0
)
SELECT NUMBER, 
        RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 130) + CASE
                                        WHEN BITS = ''
                                        THEN '0'
                                        ELSE REVERSE(BITS)
                                    END, 130) AS BIN_VALUE
FROM A
WHERE NUMBER = 0
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: It would help your answers if you added explanation as to what you changed and why. I had to use a diff tool to see that you had changed `NUMBER / 2` to `NUMBER * 0.5` and added the `option (maxrecursion 0)`

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it works with the example I've provided, but now I've realized it fails with various larger values because the arithmetic overflow returns. It seems I run into this problem: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18997/why-does-1037-1-throw-an-arithmetic-overflow-error  I haven't yet been able to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: you could get back the decimal due to multiplication *0.5 by splitting the number in two parts after multiplying with 0.1. The high part fits in 37 digits, while the low part is added after round(). You will need to adjust the length of the char part since the binary of 999..99 (9x38 times) does not fit in 125 chars...

Comment: Thanks a lot @lptr! If I could upvote your answer a second time I would :)