# SQL Server retain decimal scale and precision for operations on very lage numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, largenumber

Following [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61483940/convert-base-10-to-base-2-in-sql-server-for-very-large-numbers) I am still struggling with an arithmetic overflow error in SQL Server 2017. How can I perform a multiplication/division of a large `decimal(38,0)` value and retain/regain both the precision and scale?

In my current example I simply want to halve `DECLARE @var1 decimal(38,0) = 85070591730234615865699536669866196992;` (and truncate the result if `@var1` were odd). From [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18997/why-does-1037-1-throw-an-arithmetic-overflow-error) I have gathered that even if I do not attempt to divide by 2 but multiply by 0.5 instead I would still not obtain a `decimal(38,0)` result. I could divide by 2,000,000 to make the result fit the resulting `decimal(38,6)` type, but considering the [multiplication rules etc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) I can't figure out how to get back to `decimal(38,0)`.

Comment: If you are dividing, why not just `CAST`/`CONVERT` the result back to a `decimal(38,0)` (and lose any decimals that have been added)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is specific to your specific question -- dividing by 2.  If you want a more general solution, please ask a new question.

Dividing by 2 is the same as multiplying by 5 and dividing by 10.

We cannot multiply your value by 5, but we can do the following:

- Integer divide by 10.
- Multiply by 5.
- Add in a little bit extra to account for the missing digit.

But . . . you are thinking . . . how can we divide by 10?  Well, you can do that with *string* operations:  just truncate the last digit:

```
declare @var1 decimal(38,0) = 85070591730234615865699536669866196992;

select (convert(decimal(38,0), left(convert(varchar(38), @var1), 37)) * 5 +
        convert(decimal(38, 0), (@var1 % 10) / 2)
       ) as half_a_big_value
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e297ebacdc5c2aa55edef35d3096cc18) is a db<>fiddle.